# Configure/Install the New Blade HP Proliant BL685c G7 in Blade server C7000 G7 server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, installation, hp, blade-server, blade-chassis

I have a problem Installing the **Blade HP Proliant BL685c G7** into the **Blade server C7000 encloser G7**. i want to install Windows server 2012 R2 on the new Blade but when i boot from the Bootable USB i get the ERROR, as Mentioned Below [This is the Error When i boot the New Server, Please Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT4sC.png) can some Share the Way to configure and install the New Blade in the Encloser.

i have tried to look for all Possible Docx but couldnt help myself , it will be really good to have any Help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're on the latest firmware for that P712m, so I'd suggest you check your cabling meets the required layout for that and the SAS Interconnects you must have in you C7K. Other than that there's a chance you have a broken component but it looks like a cabling/SAS-interconnect config issue - perhaps post some details of that?

Comment: Are you using external storage for this Blade server?

Comment: we have connected MDS600 for the storage to the blade server

Comment: @Chopper3 , i didnt get you, can you please explain it. THanks

Comment: show how you've connected the MDS600 to the C7000 and any SAS Interconnect configs you've made

Comment: @Chopper3 , I have found that i have Redundant Cabling Between MDS600 and the C7000 and P712m doesn't support redundant Cabling.
and My problem is , i cant change Redundant cabling because there are 6 other Blade with p710M card .

so Now my Question is can you suggest , which card is compatible with Proliant BL685c and Also Support redundant Cabling.

Comment: I don't believe any BL685 G7 SAS card can support redundant cabling sorry.